# Making multiple apps in android studio share source code

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been asked to white label an application I am making which has resulted in me needed a project with the exact same code base, but a different manifest and different resources files. Is there currently a way to do that supported by android studio? Or is the only way to try to do it with multiple full projects and updating both?

Comment: The simplest option is to set up product flavors, and for your described scenario it should work well. For substantially more complex scenarios, split the app out into a library module (for the logic reused among all apps) and one app per customer, where the customer apps depend upon the library module.

Comment: Here is the documentation on using gradle product flavors. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants

Comment: Thank you both, product flavors are exactly what I was looking for.